# How to get NuGet package authors in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, nuget, package, nuget-package

I want to get a NuGet packages information. I have already script , like this:

```
@( Get-Project -All | ? { $_.ProjectName } | %  {
Get-Package -ProjectName $_.ProjectName } ) | ? { $_.LicenseUrl } | % {
$pkg  = $_ ;
```

$pkg.Id is accessible
$pkg.LicenseUrl is accessible

But I cannot understand when I print $pkg , the output contains Id, Versions,ProjectName. How to acces LicenseUrl .

**$pkg.Authors is not accessible** . I cannot any script for getting autohers from NugetPackages. Pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the [NuGet API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/search-query-service-resource):

```
function Get-PackageAuthors {
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )]
        [string]$Id,

        [Uri]$Url = "https://api-v2v3search-0.nuget.org"
    )
    process {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod "${Url}query?q=${Id}&take=1"
        if ($response.totalHits -gt 0) {
            return $response.data.authors
        }
    }
}

# usage:
Get-Package | Get-PackageAuthors
```

Comment: @Aslı See my edit. `Invoke-RestMethod` is actually best fitted.

Comment: great job. please add a comma after "ValueFromPipeline = $true"